# Showing popup after user registration using the "Popup message" module

Tags: 7, users, javascript

How do I show a popup to a user after he/she has registered, using the [**Popup message**](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_message) module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with [Popup message](https://www.drupal.org/project/popup_message) but this will work:

Install [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), then create a rule with the following settings:

- React on event: After saving a new user account
- Actions: Show a message on the site (your message)

Drupal will show your message as a system message.

Comment: Will an HTML message be rendered so?

Comment: Or does it only take in plain text ?

Comment: @pNg yes you can use HTML in the message

Comment: Getting started with rules, right? But I don't think you can show the message as a "popup" (as in the question). Agree? Would be nice if the popup message module would come with an extra Rules Action to ... show a popup message ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Maybe in the future we will have the integration with Popup message, I learning a little of rules, I see that you have some good Rules answers in this site.

Comment: Yes I seem to remember I ever answered "*some*" questions about, or using, Rules ...